# AWS Athena CREATE TABLE on public S3 bucket - Error S3 bucket does not exist

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm trying to call CREATE TABLE in Athena with data from a remote S3 bucket that has been set to public access. But I am getting an error after I create the table and try to read the bucket data.
Not sure how to troubleshoot this as I am new to Athena.

Here is the S3 bucket URI (changed some numbers for privacy):
s3://sagemaker-studio-45890349XXXX-h2kl4fs8jb/data

The csv file resides in the data folder and is the only file in that folder.

Here is my code to call the CREATE TABLE:

```
# SQL statement to execute
statement = """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}.{}(
         incident_id varchar(10),
         incident_date date,
         state varchar(25),
         city_or_county varchar(25),
         address string,
         n_killed int,
         n_injured int,
         incident_url string,
         source_url string,
         incident_url_fields_missing string,
         congressional_district int,
         gun_stolen string,
         gun_type string,
         incident_characteristics string,
         latitude float,
         location_description string,
         longitude float,
         n_guns_involved int,
         notes string,
         participant_age string,
         participant_age_group string,
         participant_gender string,
         participant_name string,
         participant_relationship string,
         participant_status string,
         participant_type string,
         sources string,
         state_house_district int,
         state_senate_district int
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' LOCATION '{}'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')""".format(
    database_name, table_name_csv, s3_group_bucket_csv
)


print(statement)
```

Here is the output of the print statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dsoaws.gun_violence_csv12(
         incident_id varchar(10),
         incident_date date,
         state varchar(25),
         city_or_county varchar(25),
         address string,
         n_killed int,
         n_injured int,
         incident_url string,
         source_url string,
         incident_url_fields_missing string,
         congressional_district int,
         gun_stolen string,
         gun_type string,
         incident_characteristics string,
         latitude float,
         location_description string,
         longitude float,
         n_guns_involved int,
         notes string,
         participant_age string,
         participant_age_group string,
         participant_gender string,
         participant_name string,
         participant_relationship string,
         participant_status string,
         participant_type string,
         sources string,
         state_house_district int,
         state_senate_district int
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION 's3://sagemaker-studio-45890349XXXX-h2kl4fs8jb/data'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

Now when I try to do a read_sql() with this code:

```
df = pd.read_sql(statement, conn)
df.head(5)
```

I get this error pasted below.  It is saying that the S3 bucket specified does not exist.  I am thinking I've got the wrong URI?  I tried prefixing it with "athena-" per another stackoverflow solution but that doesn't work.  The S3 bucket has been set to public access, so I don't see why my code cannot access it.  I am running this python notebook in SageMaker Studio.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1696         try:
-> 1697             cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
   1698             return cur

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/util.py in _wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     36         with _lock:
---> 37             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     38 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/cursor.py in execute(self, operation, parameters, work_group, s3_staging_dir, cache_size, cache_expiration_time)
    105         else:
--> 106             raise OperationalError(query_execution.state_change_reason)
    107         return self

OperationalError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: YH6ZT33TV7WS5K2R; S3 Extended Request ID: tWecayjY5h4IxrNDwK0x93u/dQN2kRe/NbBEjfcubOQ6jaAF4gsxik8gugOOkuy/iHLLbssdqtJyPThrWLfJ/A==; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: tWecayjY5h4IxrNDwK0x93u/dQN2kRe/NbBEjfcubOQ6jaAF4gsxik8gugOOkuy/iHLLbssdqtJyPThrWLfJ/A== (Path: s3://athena-sagemaker-studio-45890349XXXX-h2kl4fs8jb/data)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotSupportedError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1700             try:
-> 1701                 self.con.rollback()
   1702             except Exception as inner_exc:  # pragma: no cover

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyathena/connection.py in rollback(self)
    241     def rollback(self) -> None:
--> 242         raise NotSupportedError

NotSupportedError: 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-243de01eb76a> in <module>
      6 #print(statement)
      7 
----> 8 df = pd.read_sql(statement, conn)
      9 df.head(5)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    488             coerce_float=coerce_float,
    489             parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 490             chunksize=chunksize,
    491         )
    492 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
   1741 
   1742         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
-> 1743         cursor = self.execute(*args)
   1744         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
   1745 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1704                     f"Execution failed on sql: {args[0]}\n{exc}\nunable to rollback"
   1705                 )
-> 1706                 raise ex from inner_exc
   1707 
   1708             ex = DatabaseError(f"Execution failed on sql '{args[0]}': {exc}")

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql: SELECT * FROM dsoaws.gun_violence_csv12
    WHERE state = 'California' LIMIT 100
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: YH6ZT33TV7WS5K2R; S3 Extended Request ID: tWecayjY5h4IxrNDwK0x93u/dQN2kRe/NbBEjfcubOQ6jaAF4gsxik8gugOOkuy/iHLLbssdqtJyPThrWLfJ/A==; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: tWecayjY5h4IxrNDwK0x93u/dQN2kRe/NbBEjfcubOQ6jaAF4gsxik8gugOOkuy/iHLLbssdqtJyPThrWLfJ/A== (Path: s3://athena-sagemaker-studio-45890349XXXX-h2kl4fs8jb/data)
unable to rollback
```

Comment: Does the `sagemaker-studio-45890349XXXX-h2kl4fs8jb` bucket exist?

Comment: Yes, but I put inthe XXXX's because it's my colleague's bucket and I wasn't sure if I should expose its ID on the internet.

Comment: Just found this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390240/aws-athena-read-external-s3-bucket but what are they referring to as the "requisite" roles and permissions under the first Answer bullet point #1 and #2?

Comment: Ah! When you mentioned a "remote S3 bucket", are you saying that the bucket is owned by a different AWS Account??

Comment: yes my colleague made the bucket on their AWS account but my colleague and I want to share the bucket for data purposes.  It's not sensitive data.